# Post on Facebook Page using Force.com Facebook Toolkit

Tags: facebook

Using Facebook Toolkit i am able to get data of user. But is it possible to post data on Facebook page and get data from Facebook page.
Please provide me the relevant code for posting on Facebook Page.

Comment: Himanshu, could you be more specific on what exactly you're trying to do, and how far you've already gotten ?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you would do would be to obtain the Facebook page ID - this is simply the bit of the page URL after `https://www.facebook.com/` - so, the Developer Force Facebook page ID is `forcedotcom`.

Now, to get the posts (feed) for that page:

```
posts = new FacebookPosts(accessToken, pageid +'/feed', null);
```

To post to that page:

```
FacebookPublish.postToWall(accessToken, pageid, new Map<String, String>{'message' => message});
```

You can edit the [sample page controller](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-Facebook/blob/master/src/classes/FacebookSampleController.cls) in the Facebook Toolkit to try this out - look for `myPosts` and `postToFeed()` and change `me` to a page ID:

```
public FacebookPosts myPosts {
    get {
        try {
            String accessToken = getAccessToken();

            if (accessToken != null) {
                myPosts = new FacebookPosts(accessToken, 'forcedotcom/feed', null);
            }               
        } catch (Exception e) {
            error = e.getMessage();
        }

        return myPosts;
    } set;
}

// Further down...

public PageReference postToFeed() {
    error = null;

    try {
        if (message != null) {
            FacebookPublish.postToWall(getAccessToken(), 'forcedotcom', new Map<String, String>{'message' => message});
        }

        message = null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        error = e.getMessage();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: thanks,
HI now i need to send private message to other users of facebook from salesforce. I am able to send message using Java Script SDK from salesforce, but the message look like
    message
    This attachment may have been removed or the person who shared it may not have permission to share it with you.

I want to send direct message using graph api.
help.

Comment: You can't send a direct message using the graph api. It's not possible - see http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/33365/67

Comment: When i am sending message using **Java Script SDK** i am able to send message but also getting an warning message along with my message.
Warning or Error is as : **This attachment may have been removed or the person who shared it may not have permission to share it with you.**
How can i remove the warning message.

Comment: Answered on your other question.