# How do I use the Force.com Toolkit for Facebook to send a Private Message?

Tags: facebook

I need to send a private message from Salesforce to Facebook using the Facebook REST API. I have the access_key, app_key, and user id. I can send a private message by using JavaScript given by Facebook `FB.init` but for that we need to login by providing username and password if the user is not logged in in that browser. I need to send a private message via the REST API. By reading the Facebook docs, I see that Facebook uses SASL Authentication for chat. What are the endpoint url and parameter for sending private messages?

Answer (score 1):

It's not currently possible from the Force.com Toolkit for Facebook. The Facebook REST (Graph) API doesn't allow it - see the [doc page on message](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/message) - there is only GET, no POST. The only thing you can do is [use the JavaScript SDK to let the user send a message](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog) from a Visualforce page.

Looking at the [Facebook Chat docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/), there is a PHP example there with the endpoint (`chat.facebook.com`) and code to send messages.